# Any idea to create the price table which associate with date in Django(Python)

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I would like to create a price table by date, I tried to google this for python and django, but still have no idea for this. I don't want to create one to one relationship object like an options. but I would like to create the database associating date and price. Sorry that it may be simple question..
Would it be solution to create a database by using PostgreSQL, and read by django? or any resource / reference can help get me in right direction to access this problem?

Thanks so much

Comment: An actual outline example of what you want would be helpful. For one I'm not sure what the association between price and date would be?

Comment: Actually I would like to create a reservation system like hotel, I need to assign the price to the calendar. like hotel.com or booking.com. Would it be difficult for newbie of programming and django?

Answer (score 0):

Well there is more to it then assigning a price to a date. You will need one or more tables that hold the establishment(hotels) data. These would include the room information as all rooms will not have the same price. Also the price will probably change over time, so you will need to track that. Then there is the reservation information to track. This is just some of the basics. It is not a simple task by any means. I would try a simpler project to start with to learn Django and how to get data in and out of it.